# not able to understand entrySet() method

Tags: java, hashmap

We can use an entrySet() method to iterate over the hashmap key-value pairs stored in Node[] table field .

```
HahMap<K,V> hashmap = new HashMap<>() ;

public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() 
{
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

When we use this in a for-each loop like :

```
for ( Map.Entry<K,V> entry : hashmap.entrySet () ) 
{
... 
// entry is an object of return type Map.Entry and object type Node . 
// got the object type by calling entry.getClass() and also no other inner class other than Node implements Map.Entry .   ; 

}
```

These objects are stored in a Set . But where is the code which links them to the field table which has key-value pairs .

For example :
In toString() method when we get Iterable using iterator() method , and call next() method on Iterable the call goes to nextNode() of HashIterator class where the object returned is linked to table field of HashMap class .
But what happens here ? Please help .

Comment: This `EntrySet`  is an inner class of `HashMap`, and it has access to all the values of the map . See here : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.EntrySet

Comment: i can't see the required code .

Comment: `entrySet` is a class variable of HashMap. The code of `entrySet()` says something like: if entrySet of HashMap is null then return new EntrySet else return HashMap's entrySet. Adding an element to the hashMap calls `addEntry()` which adds the element to hashMap's `entrySet`

Comment: @Obenland there is no addEntry() method in my  HashMap class .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to lack the understanding of what a *view* is. A *view* has no stored data, but just fulfills a certain interface by delegating to the actual data object.

A simple example is the list *view* created via `Collections.unmodifiableList(…)` which does not contain any data, but delegates all method calls to the original list, excluding the modification methods, of course.

The entry set fulfills the `Set` interface by delegating to the underlying map. Most notably, by returning an `Iterator`, as most methods are build upon this, only a few others are overridden for performance, e.g. `size()` delegates directly to the map’s `size()`. So if it appears as if the entry set contains something, it is, because the iterator reports it during the traversal.

The `Hashmap`’s entry set iterator iterates over the internal array of entries, just like the key set iterator and the value collection iterator. The only difference between them is which object they return in the `next()` method, the entry set iterator just returns the entry, the other two extract the key resp. value of the entry. That’s why these iterator only override that single method.

Note that this interaction can also be seen the other way round. When you implement a `Map` by extending [`AbstractMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html), the `entrySet()` is the *only* method you need to implement, all other map methods are already implemented via delegation to the entry set. You might override some of them for performance, though. But the question, which actually contains the data, is moot, both, the `Map` and the entry `Set` are views to the same underlying data.

Maybe the following example helps:

```
String[][] pairs={ {"foo","bar"}, {"hello","world"} };

Map<String,String> map = new AbstractMap<String, String>() {
    public Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        return new AbstractSet<Entry<String, String>>() {
            public Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator() {
                return Arrays.stream(pairs)
                    .<Entry<String,String>>map(p -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(p[0],p[1]))
                    .iterator();
            }
            public int size() {
                return pairs.length;
            }
        };
    }
};

System.out.println(map.get("foo"));
System.out.println(map.containsKey("hello"));
System.out.println(map.containsValue("world"));
map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+" -> "+v));
System.out.println(map);
```

It creates an immutable map that is never put into. Still, it reports the intended contents through all `Map` methods, just because the entry set iterator reports this content.

Comment: Are trying to say this ? Inside entrySet() method : Set<Map.Entry> entrySet = new EntrySet () ; return entrySet ;  and then call goes to entrySet.iterator().next() and this iterates over the internal array of entries .

Answer (score 0):

If I have not missed anything from your question: `EntrySet` overrides `iterator` method (making it an `Iterable` to be used in forEach) that in turn returns an `EntryIterator` - it overrides the `next` method:

```
public final Map.Entry<K,V> next() { return nextNode(); }
```

But it also extends `HashIterator` that defines the `hasNext` method.

It is actually as simple as that. But generally these are inner classes - and they have access to everything they might need in the `HashMap` class.

Comment: As per my understanding , do elements of Set<Map.Entry> entrySet are initialized by call to iterator() method of class EntryMap when we call entrySet() method .

Comment: @steve they are not initialized... they are already in place in the `Map` - the only thing is that they get iterated.

Comment: @steve I don't get you at all... can you may be make that more clear for me?

Comment: I mean to say : We get Set<Map.Entry> entrySet returned in the for loop , and we get the elements of this Set one by one , but to get them , they have to be first inserted using put() method , how  are they inserted ?

Comment: @steve ok... this is even more confusing right now. they are inserted via the `put` method obviously. Consider simpler that `put` will put entries in an array, and `EntrySet` would just iterate that array. I do understand that you have something that you don't understand, but I can't understood you to actually help